# Embedding article template with many entry tags

Tags: templates, embeds, dry

I’m working on a blog and would love to make the markup for a single article its own template for embedding elsewhere so I don't have to repeat that markup in multiple places, but I don't know how to do this and still parse all entry tags. The markup for a single article will appear in multiple templates (`blog/index`, `blog/single`, etc.) and is exactly the same. Currently it appears like this in my `blog/index` template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" dynamic="no"}
    {if post_theme}
        {post_theme}<article class="theme-{theme}" style="background-color: {background_color};">{/post_theme}
    {if:else}
        <article>
    {/if}
        <div class="interior">
            <header class="article-header {header_options}col-start-{col_start} col-end-{col_end} overlay-{headline_overlay} headline-size-{headline_size}{/header_options}">
                <h5><a href="{page_url}"><time>{entry_date format='%j %F %Y'}</time></a></h5>
                {categories}
                    <h2><a href="{path='blog/index'}">{category_name}</a></h2>
                {/categories}
                <h1>{title}</h1>
            </header>
            {blog_cover_image}
                {if image}
                    <figure class="cover-image {image_width}">
                        {if '{image_width}' == 'full-width'}
                            {exp:ce_img:single src="{image}" add_dims="yes" width="750" attributes='alt="{alt_text}"'}
                        {if:elseif '{image_width}' == 'text-width'}
                            {exp:ce_img:single src="{image}" add_dims="yes" width="500" attributes='alt="{alt_text}"'}
                        {/if}
                        {if caption}
                            <figcaption>
                                {caption}
                            </figcaption>
                        {/if}
                    </figure>
                {/if}
            {/blog_cover_image}
            <aside>
                <ul class="article-tags">
                    {exp:tag:tags
                        entry_id="{entry_id}"
                        orderby="tag_name"
                        sort="asc"
                    }
                        <li><a href="{path='blog/tag'}/{websafe_tag}" title="{tag}" style="font-size:{step}px;">{tag}</a></li>
                    {/exp:tag:tags}
                </ul>
            </aside>
            <div class="article-content">
                {blog_images}
                    {exp:mx_jumper:put name="image_{row_count}"}
                        <figure class="{placement} {size}">
                            {if '{size}' == 'full-width'}
                                {exp:ce_img:single src="{image}" add_dims="yes" width="750" attributes='alt="{alt_text}"'}
                            {if:elseif '{size}' == 'text-width'}
                                {exp:ce_img:single src="{image}" add_dims="yes" width="500" attributes='alt="{alt_text}"'}
                            {if:else}
                                {exp:ce_img:single src="{image}" add_dims="yes" attributes='alt="{alt_text}"'}
                            {/if}
                            {if caption}
                                <figcaption>
                                    {caption}
                                </figcaption>
                            {/if}
                        </figure>
                    {/exp:mx_jumper:put}
                {/blog_images}
                {exp:mx_jumper:out_global}
                    {blog_post_content}
                {/exp:mx_jumper:out_global}
                {if external_links}
                    <div class="external-links">
                        {external_links}
                    </div>
                {/if}
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="article-footer">
            <div class="interior">
                <ul class="tools">
                    <li class="permalink"><a href="{page_url}">Permalink</a></li>
                    <li class="tweet"><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/home?status={page_url}">Tweet</a></li>
                    <li class="pinterest"><a target="_blank" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={page_url}">Pinterest</a></li>
                    <li class="facebook"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={page_url}">Facebook</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </article>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Here is what I would rather do:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" dynamic="no"}
    {embed="blog/.article"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I need everything between my `{exp:channel:entries}` tag to be an embed, but I don't know what to pass it so that all entry tags are parsed.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I couldn't found nothing that looks like a snippet on your code, you can use one.

Save all the internal code of `exp:channel:entries` tags on a snippet called `snip_article` and go ahead!

If you want a way to edit snippets as plain text files, give to [SnippetsSync](https://github.com/bjornbjorn/snippetssync.ee2_addon/) a try.